# Can I Share The List Of Build Files In The Ant View In Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Intellij IDEA displays the ant build file(s) in a tree view in a tool window. The list of files and any extra params (such as memory etc) are saved in the .idea/ant.xml file, which I check in to version control so that when the project is checked out it is clear what/how to build.

See [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-scala/blob/master/.idea/ant.xml) for an example of a project that lists multiple build files in this file (note how everything is relative to the project directory).

Eclipse has a similar [Ant View](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-85a_ant_view.htm) but I can't see where the configuration is stored. I would rather not have to tell every new developer "drag these 3 xml files to the ant view after you have checked out the project".

Does eclipse have an equivalent of .idea/ant.xml that I can check in to version control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an "External Build" configuration that runs Ant and you can set that configuration to reside in an external file that can be stored in the VC system.

**1**

In Eclipse this brings up the menu

```
Run > External Tools > External Tools Configuration
```

**2**

Create an Ant build and specify all the params and the targets to run. (You can also do this by editing the build.xml file, looking at the outline view and right-clicking on a target and selecting `Run as ... > Ant build ...`)

**3**

Then use this  to create the file that gets version controlled.

```
Common > Save As "Shared File" and[ browse to a folder in your workspace]
```

**4**

Those files you create this way can be launched by right clicking and choosing `"Run as ..."`